# C# escape & char in arguments path when running cmd.exe /C

Tags: c#, .net, cmd

Please could someone advise how I can escape an '&' character in a string when trying to start a process like the following:

```
            var arguments = $"/C \"C:\\Here & Here\\MyExe.exe\"";
            Process process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    Arguments = arguments,
                    FileName = "cmd.exe",
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                    UseShellExecute = false
                }
            };
            process.Start();
```

I need to execute the process using cmd.exe /C I've tried replacing the string with to use a ^& 
like this:

```
var arguments = $"/C \"C:\\Here ^& Here\\MyExe.exe\"";
```

but it still doesn't find the path.

In a cmd window i would just do `cmd.exe /C ""C:\Here ^& Here\MyExe.exe""` and it works just not via a process start

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to breakout the `&` in the cmd instance or the C# instance or both? What is the literal path of the file.

Comment: No there's a & in the path to the file i just want to pass it in as part of the arguments some reason i cant seem to escape the char. In a cmd window i would just do this cmd.exe /C ""C:\Here ^& Here\MyExe.exe"" and it works just not via a process start

Comment: Try this instead:  `var arguments = @"/C ""C:\Here ^& Here\MyExe.exe""";`

Comment: Thanks but Still returning the same exit code 1..

Comment: Before the `&` try putting the `*` wildcard character and see if it works. So it would be `var arguments = $"/C \"C:\\Here *\\MyExe.exe\"";`

Comment: No sorry still the same :(

Comment: Why pass the path as an argument into cmd.exe instead of just launching the desired EXE with your process.Start()?

Comment: Correct you must turn off UseShellExecute if you want to run as another user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine if the path is double-quoted:

```
var arguments = "/c \"\"C:\\Here & Here\\MyExe.exe\"\"";
```